# Shutter is running, but I don't see it

Tags: 12.04, shutter

I installed shutter yesterday, and it worked great, but I couldn't get it to run today. So I looked around AskUbuntu, and installed the dependencies I was missing and that still didn't solve my problem. Then I type `shutter` in the terminal, I get `INFO: There is already another instance of Shutter running!`. I don't see it anywhere and it's not marked as running in my sidebar. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, purging and installing through the terminal, but nothing helped, I still get the same problem. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Since I can't up vote, just want to say it worked for me.
Although I've used [this ppa from official site.](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/) ` sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get shutter running by:

1. Purging my current install `sudo apt-get purge shutter`
2. Installing Shutter from their PPA: http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/ppa-installation-guide/
3. Running `killall shutter` to remove active Shutter processes if any
4. Running `shutter -f` which captures the whole screen and displays it in Shutter.

After this, Shutter is working as it should.

Comment: `sudo kill pid` - pid represents shutter's processid.Killing the shutter's pid will does the job for you.This command `ps aux | grep shutter | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'` will help you to get shutter's pid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your shutter cannot connect through unix socket:

---

```
$ shutter
WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be disabled!

WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be disabled!

*** unhandled exception in callback:
***   Can't connect to display `unix:0': No such file or directory at
/usr/share/perl5/X11/Protocol.pm line 2264
***  ignoring at /usr/share/shutter/resources/modules/Shutter/Screenshot/Main.pm  (..)
```

---

There seems to be no solutuion - ist's a bug that Ubuntu does not create /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
The only solution I know is to logout and login again - that creates socket file.

Manipulating system with

```
xhost +
```

Gives no result.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here!

I did that:

```
 ps -edaf | grep shutter
```

and then... (some of these may are not so valid - please check )

( run *kill at your terminal to see which of these commands you have, and *kill --help to read about them. )

```
sudo rkill -9  pidNumber
sudo kill -9   pidNumber
sudo tkill -9  pidNumber
sudo pkill -9  pidNumber
sudo skill -9  pidNumber
sudo kill -9  pidNumber
```

I dont know which of these commands shutdown the shutter process that was not shown on my task manager, - i run them all together - but shutter was eventually killed.

Answer (score -2):

Find the process ID

```
ps ax | grep shutter
```

then kill em and restart shutter

```
kill -9 process_id
shutter
```

Comment: That's essentially what `killall shutter` does in the accepted answer.